# Android listview item height fill_parent does not work

Tags: android, listview, height, fill

I have an android app with a mainactivity that contain a listview, this is the code of the main activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView  android:id="@+id/commandList" 
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="0dp"
               android:layout_weight="1"
              />

</LinearLayout>
```

in the listview I display a partial view, this is the code of view layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/commandText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

I wish that the elements would fill the height of mainactivitylayout but the result is this:
[result image](http://it.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=14marl1&s=5#.Us0G7_Z-57c)[image]

thank you regards

Comment: what do u want here to be done??? I'm not getting "the elements would fill the height of mainactivitylayout"... can u explain in brief?

Comment: post your custom adapter as well

Comment: If you want the list items to fill the entire area, then it totally kills the purpose of using ListView. Instead, simply place your items on your main layout.

Comment: When your list has more items it will automatically fill the screen ! You should rather use static views then, or if you want to use listview only you could add a insane amount of padding to make it fullscreen, but seriously don't do that !

Comment: asked a different way: I need to use a ListView because I don't know how many items I have until run time, and I want that list view to fill the parent view height no matter what. That doesn't seem unreasonable, and it should be simple to accomplish. It's not, however

Answer (score 6):

`Waqas` is right in above comment. (It totally kills the purpose of using ListView)

But still you want to implement this then in getView() of adapter try below code

```
convertView.getLayoutParams().height = parent.getHeight() / NO_OF_ITEMS;
convertView.requestLayout();
```

Comment: Problem if the number reaches a high amount of items for the list.. if 50 or so, the items will not be big enough to display the text..

Comment: @AndersMetnik Yeh..I know..for that we have to check for item number.

Comment: it doesn't totally kill the reason for using a list view; why can't we have both? You need to dynamically incorporate the rows for the list view, which you don't know ahead of time, and, you want the list view to fill its parent height. That's not unreasonable; that's decent UI.

Comment: if set height crashes use. `vi.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,parent.getHeight() / NO_OF_ITEMS));`